# How can I do the following steps using brew instead of yum?

Tags: python, homebrew

I keep having a problem regarding the setup with a script, I found a possible  [solution](https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli/issues/603) to my problem but they are only using yum, I tried to use brew and follow the steps but it keeps happening the same problem. I am still new using brew so I was wondering if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!!

```
# sudo pip uninstall requests
# sudo pip uninstall urllib3
# sudo yum remove python-urllib3
# sudo yum remove python-requests
Confirm all the above libraries have been removed by executing the below command:

# rpm -qa | grep requests 
# pip freeze | grep requests
Now, install those packages using yum:

# sudo yum install python-urllib3
# sudo yum install python-requests
```

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more details about your `python` installation through `homebrew`.

Comment: Yes, I have install a pyenv pyenv install 3.9.4
pyenv install 2.7.17
pyenv global 3.9.4 2.7.17

Comment: @RandomPerson not enough details to see what went wrong  - include some outputs of what fails. Please read this, however: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask